# Adding content into html from text file using jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to the jquery aspect of things. Supplied below is my html/jquery code which is used to pull text file contents. However, I can't seem to get it working. The test.txt file contains "testtest" within the first line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="text"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#text').load("C:/Users/MYUSER/Desktop/test.txt");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is probably two problems, first, you can load a content inside a input field, the second, i think is not possible load a file directly from your directory

Comment: @alexqoliveira would it be possible to do this with an html file?

Comment: No. In chrome, for example, this error occurs: 'Cross-source requests are supported only for protocol schemas: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource'.

But in firefox you will achive what you trying to do. Try load on on firefox but this time call a method 'load' an a div tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the jQuery.get you can read the text file and use html method to assign the value to paragraph.

```
jQuery.get('file.txt', function(data) {
   alert(data);
   //process text file line by line
   $('#text').html(data.replace('n',''));
});
```

Refer to the link for more information.
https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-read-text-file/

Comment: I can't use this locally however can I? I will need some sort of web service?

Comment: use ajax when fetching from the webservice

Answer (score -1):

You cannot read a file from your local file system this way, you need to put it on web server and load/read it from there.

Another option, you can start chrome using option --allow-file-access-from-files, which would allow access to local files. For more reference see http://chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.blogspot.in/